# Rails Mailboxer - unable to find the recipient domain on sending email via smtp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, smtp, actionmailer

I am using mailboxer gem in my Rails application. 
Following are the 2 methods in my User model, which is messageable -

```
def name
    return :email
  end

  def mailboxer_email(object)
    #Check if an email should be sent for that object
    #if true
    # mail(:to => :email, :subject => "Your Login credential")
    return :email
    #if false
    #return nil
  end
```

And following are my smtp settings in my development.rb file -

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => 587,
:authentication => :plain,
:domain => 'gmail.com',
:user_name => 'address@gmail.com',
:password => 'mypassword',
:authentication => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

But on creating a message, i am getting the following error -

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22136ms



 Net::SMTPFatalError (553-5.1.2 We weren't able to find the recipient domain. Please check for any
    553-5.1.2 spelling errors, and make sure you didn't enter any spaces, periods,
    553 5.1.2 or other punctuation after the recipient's email address. eg3sm14283691pac.1 - gsmtp
    ):

  `app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:12:in `create`'
```

I am sure I am sending the email to a proper email address. Also, when i put debugger in mailboxer_email method, the email I see is valid one.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error:- "We weren't able to find the recipient domain"

by setting up the domain => 'gmail.com'

You should specify the

```
:domain =>  'your application name'   ( :domain => 'foo.com' or 'http://localhost:3000' )
```

also setup

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

you change according production, development environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gaurav. I tried it, but its still throwing me the same error.